# Prove that any finite poset is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb {N}$ ordered by divisibility rule

Tags: order-theory

Prove that any finite poset is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb {N}$ ordered by divisibility rule.

---

I have no idea how to prove this so any hints would be much appriciated.

Comment: What makes you think  that this is true? Have you checked a few cases to see if it holds true?

Answer (score 6):

Given any finite poset $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ and any set of $n$ distinct primes $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$ (e.g. the first $n$ primes), the poset can be embedded in $(\mathbb{N}, \vert)$ via the map that sends $x_i$ to the product of the primes $p_j$ over those indices $j$ for which $x_j \le x_i$.

Comment: "the poset can be embedded in.." means it is isomorphic to..? Also does that mean that any finite poset is isomorphic to a set of distinct primes?

Comment: No, the poset is isomorphic to a set of squarefree numbers ordered by divisibility, which does not necessarily contain only primes.

Comment: where does this come from? I somehow don't see why and how it works.

Comment: Any poset can be embedded inside its power set ordered by inclusion via the map $x \mapsto \{y: y \le x\}$. For a finite set with $n$ elements, the power set ordered by inclusion is isomorphic to the poset of divisors of the primorial of the $n$th prime ($p_n\#$) ordered by divisibility.